# Dynamic localization.strings definitions for an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dynamic, localization

Is there a way that I can download **Localizable.strings** from my web-server to support multiple languages without rebuilding my iOS app every-time?

The default method need the language file to be in resources directory NOT *documents* directory of the bundle and *Lang_Name.lproj* directory.

Is there a custom category or addition to **NSLocalizedString** to use **lang_name.strings** file from downloaded directory (*documents*)

Comment: +1, Have you found any solutions ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: you can achieve something *similar*, but you'll need to code your own wrapper for it. You can't dynamically swap out the localised strings file, but you could create your own NSLocalizedStrings replacement that, say, downloaded an XML file and parsed it upon app launch to get the required strings.

Comment: Any links or leads on how do the suggestion you have provided?